# How to send bulk SMS with twilio API

Tags: twilio

I want to sending bulk SMS with Twilio is this possible with Twilio exists API. I have searching few hours with google, but can't find acceptable answers. So, I decide to asking at here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't mentioned platform for which you want to use this API

Answer (score 13):

[SMS and MMS Quickstart Tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/sending-via-rest)

This sample is using a `dictionary` to send messages to group of people, see at following sample code in above link.

```
// make an associative array of people we know, indexed by phone number
    var people = new Dictionary<string,string>() { 
        {"+14158675309","Curious George"},
        {"+14158675310","Boots"},
        {"+14158675311","Virgil"}
    };
```

More Over as You have mentioned **BULK Messaging** I would like you to have a look at their policy of Do's and Dont's also at [this link](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-kind-of-sms-messages-are-not-allowed-to-be-sent-using-twilio)

and look for section **Sending mass marketing or bulk messaging using Twilio long code phone numbers**

Have a look at

- [REST API: Short Codes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/short-codes)
- [REST API: Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message)

Answer (score 7):

Yes and no, yes you can send 'batch' MMS by iterating thru a list of numbers you want to send to, but if you plan on sending a lot, you are going to want to lease a short-code (for about $1000/month) in order to qualify for the higher sending limits.

With a regular number you can send at most one message per second. With a shortcode, you can up that to 30 messages per second.

You might be able to get away with low-level 'bulk' sms on a regular twilio number, but don't be surprised if you get shut down if you are spamming or violating the terms of use (see Boosters post above for the link).

Comment: Just to be clear, you can make requests to the Twilio REST API as fast as you want, however, Twilio will queue outbound sms messages and release them at a rate of one per second.

Comment: Is it possible to know the status of each of the sms messages sent with the REST API, if i attach a **statusCallback** in my request ?

Comment: @shasikanth, you can use periodic polling to check on the status of the individual messages using the API, or you can use the `statusCallback` webhook which will be called whenever the status changes.