# Using Twilio to broadcast a text to speech message to over 1000 phone numbers

Tags: twilio

I have an application that allows a user to send a message to multiple contacts.  I've reviewed the API for Twilio and it appears the only way to call multiple numbers is to iterate over a list of numbers.  Some of the users will be sending a message to over a 1000 numbers and making 1000 REST requests seems very inefficient.  Is there a way to create contacts in Twilio and add them to a group and then just send a request to call the group and play the message? I'm basically looking for something that acts more like a batch request instead of 1000 individual requests?

I've seen another question that referenced sending bulk, but it the answers didn't really say yes or no and the examples were incomplete and the question is closed.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send bulk SMS with twilio API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418801/how-to-send-bulk-sms-with-twilio-api)

Comment: Thanks.  I reviewed the original question and it was closed.  The answers are also vague.  Plus, there is no reference to groups as I have asked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

One possible way you could do that, is by creating a conference room, and dropping all your users there.

You can then play the message after a few seconds once you know all your users have been dropped there.

With conference rooms, you have the ability to mute, so you could potentially start the room muted, and then play the message to everyone.

Right now, one limitation I can think of, if the fact that as of the time of writing, the conference rooms have a limitation of 40 participants, but there's nothing stopping you from spinning up multiple rooms that would help you reach those 1000 users you want to reach.

Here's some reading that might interest you.

- [TwiML Voice:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference)
- [Moderated Conferencing](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/moderated-conference)

Hope this helps you